# I want to make an Script in python which will calculate Beneish M Score in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Table 1 – Financials (standalone)

```
Year                            2014              2013            2012            2011            2010
Net Sales                       8,020.35          9,754.50        8,433.48        6,447.24        4,827.47 
Cost of Goods                   5,524.76          7,416.64        6,299.72        4,494.74        3,176.16 
Net Receivables                 2,045.70          2,807.26        1,689.88        1,109.29        693.33 
Current Assets                  4,000.61          4,894.15        4,228.61        2,747.23        2,236.16 
Property, Plant and Equipment   1,848.27          2,177.22        1,948.19        1,834.23        1,552.22 
Depreciation                    199.02            219.18          203.06          194.05          180.10 
Total Assets                    13,994.40         13,215.16       12,186.17       10,201.72       8,480.00 
SGA Expense                     588.25            495.77          451.73          347.35          338.63 
Net Income                      673.95            423.05          345.39          379.69          283.40 
Cash Flow from Operations       988.18            1.17            406.65          340.06          1,069.19 
Current Liabilities             4,301.49          4,697.45        4,868.32        3,087.15        889.03 
Long-term Debt                  1,492.06          1,503.40        1,475.46        1,534.03        3,640.02
```

Table 2 – Financials (consolidated)

```
Year                            2014        2013        2012        2011        2010
Net Sales                       26,111.94   26,003.67   21,840.29   18,187.77   15,523.34
Cost of Goods                   10,323.87   11,543.19   9,156.12    6,872.80    5,519.23
Net Receivables                 2,642.69    3,358.56    2,220.68    1,530.03    1,083.42
Current Assets                  17,581.22   17,393.72   13,317.96   10,932.59   5,528.21
Property, Plant and Equipment   17,998.98   15,444.53   12,490.63   8,847.56    6,544.69
Depreciation                    1,608.86    1,295.49    1,092.33    940.90      866.48
Total Assets                    63,034.10   57,105.27   45,157.00   39,600.52   28,988.86
SGA Expense                     1,730.27    1,625.98    1,347.43    1,231.69    1,640.42
Net Income                      1,221.80    1,183.89    1,010.15    907.97      154.56
Cash Flow from Operations       47.62       -993.70     153.47      1,263.04    4,235.99
Current Liabilities             14,515.48   15,660.07   11,881.23   9,106.74    3,206.53
Long-term Debt                  12,460.74   9,392.73    5,641.57    4,680.65    7,432.40
```

Here from the above table I need to calculate different Indexes:

Index 1: `Days Sales in Receivables Index (DSRI) = Net Receivable [CY]/ Net Sales [CY] Divided by Net Receivable [CY-1]/ Net Sales [CY-1]`

So I thought storing all the Table 1 data in dictionary like this:

```
Net_Sales = {2014: 8020.35, 2013:9754.50, 2012:8433.48, 2011:6447.24, 2010:4827.47}
Cost_Goods = {2014: 5524.76, 2013:7416.64, 2012:6299.72, 2011:4494.74, 2010:3176.16}
Net_Receivables = {2014:2045.70, 2013:2807.26, 2012:1689.88, 2011:1109.29, 2010:693.33}
Current_Assets = {2014:4000.61, 2013:4894.15, 2012:4228.61, 2011:2747.23, 2010:2236.16}
Property_Plant_Equipment = {2014:1848.27, 2013:2177.22, 2012:1948.19, 2011:1834.23, 2010:1552.22}
Depreciation = {2014:199.02, 2013:219.18, 2012:203.06, 2011:194.05, 2010:180.10}
Total_Assets = {2014:13994.40, 2013:13215.16, 2012:12186.17, 2011:10201.72, 2010:8480.00}
SGA_Expense = {2014:588.25, 2013:495.77, 2012:451.73, 2011:347.35, 2010:338.63}
Net_Income = {2014:673.95, 2013:423.05, 2012:345.39, 2011:379.69, 2010:283.40}
Cash_Flow_Operations = {2014:988.18, 2013:1.17, 2012:406.65, 2011:340.06, 2010:1069.19}
Current_Liabilities = {2014:4301.49, 2013:4697.45, 2012:4868.32, 2011:3087.15, 2010:889.03}
Long_Deb = {2014:1492.06, 2013:1503.40, 2012:1475.46, 2011:1534.03, 2010:3640.02}
```

But then again I need to make lots of dictionary for Table 2 also.

And again I need to display the output in a table like this:

```
#Index 1 using the formula 1.
Net Receivable [CY-1]/ Sales [CY-1]
Year                            2014    2013    2012    2011
As per Standalone Financials    0.886   1.436   1.165   1.198
As per Consolidated Financials  0.784   1.270   1.209   1.205
```

I calculated the 1st value using the following formula:

```
DSRI = (Net_Receivables[2014]/Net_Sales[2014]) / (Net_Receivables[2013]/Net_Sales[2013])
```

And I got the only one value. So it would be very hectic and unplanned way to do the above calculation. As I need to do lots of calculation on the above data. So can someone help me how to store these data if not in dictionary then where. And how should I plan to calculate all the required values. As I need to calculate 8 indexes and maybe in the future I can reuse it for different set of years. Thanks. Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: It sounds a bit as if you were asking for [`for`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

Comment: I am confused here how to work with above data as I need to calculate data for different years.

Comment: Do you know what `for` is / how it is used? `for year in range(2010, 2015):` - does that look familiar to you?